# General Form for $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{d\left ( kn \right )}{n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

The function d(x) gives the number of divisors of x. "k" is a positive integer. In Mathematica, I think, d(x) is implemented as DivisorSigma[0,x]. If you know of such a General Form or can point me to a mathematical paper that discusses such infinite series, please pass it along. I have investigated k=2048 and found the sum approximately 25.0286 (k a power of 2 in this case) and k=2017 with an approximate sum of 5.41158 (k a prime number this time). Both approximations were a result of finding the partial sum of a million terms using SAGE. David H. Bailey has published much about similar infinite sums - but I can not find this one anywhere. It would not surprise me if the final answer has $\pi$ in it - like so many infinite series I've played with lately.

Comment: Are you sure this sum converge?

Comment: Do you mean $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{d_k(n)}{n^2}=(\zeta(2))^k=\frac{\pi^{2k}}{6^k}$ ?

Comment: Mathematica reports "the ratio test is inconclusive" but I am pretty sure it converges by looking at the graph of partial sums. The d(k*n) is a constant positive integer multiplying n - then the number_of_divisors function is applied.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde - the result you quoted is very interesting also. Where did it come from? But I think it is different from my question. I will have to play with that one as well.

Comment: It comes from Tom Apostol's collection of interesting Dirichlet series, see, e.g., [here](http://authors.library.caltech.edu/21471/1/Apostol2010p12265.pdf), equations $27.4.5-27.4.13$.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde - This question I asked was worth it, to just get the tip about Tom Apostol's PDF!  There's a lot of excellent information on those 13 pages !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working with the special case presented by the OP we take $q\ge 1$ and
seek to evaluate

$$L(s) = \sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{\tau(2^q n)}{n^s}.$$

Introduce $$Q(s) = \sum_{m\ge 0} \frac{\tau(2m+1)}{(2m+1)^s}.$$

This is
$$Q(s) = \zeta(s)^2 - \sum_{m\ge 1} \frac{\tau(2m)}{(2m)^s}
= \zeta(s)^2 - \sum_{k\ge 1} 
\sum_{m\ge 0} \frac{\tau(2^k(2m+1))}{(2^k(2m+1))^s}
\\ = \zeta(s)^2 - \sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{k+1}{2^{ks}}
\sum_{m\ge 0} \frac{\tau(2m+1)}{(2m+1)^s}$$

which yields

$$Q(s) \frac{1}{(1-1/2^s)^2} = \zeta(s)^2
\quad\text{or}\quad
Q(s) = (1-1/2^s)^2 \zeta(s)^2.$$

We thus obtain for $L(s)$

$$L(s) = Q(s) \sum_{k\ge 0} (q+k+1) \frac{1}{2^{ks}}
\\ = Q(s) \left(\frac{q}{(1-1/2^s)}
+ \frac{1}{(1-1/2^s)^2}\right).$$

This finally yields

$$L(s) = \zeta(s)^2 (q(1-1/2^s) + 1).$$

In particular we have for the example by the OP the value

$$\zeta(2)^2 (11\times 3/4  + 1)
= \frac{\pi^4}{36} \frac{37}{4}
= \frac{37\pi^4}{144}
\approx 25.02872479.$$

**Remark.** Treating the general case

$$L_p(s) = \sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{\tau(p^q n)}{n^s}$$

with $p\ge 2$ a prime we obtain by the same calculation that
$$Q_p(s) = (1-1/p^s)^2 \zeta(s)^2  $$

and hence

$$L_p(s) = \zeta(s)^2 (q(1-1/p^s) + 1).$$

We get for $q=1$ and $p=2017$

$$\zeta(2)^2 ((1-1/2017^2) + 1)
= \frac{\pi^4}{36}\frac{2\times 2017^2-1}{2017^2}
\approx 5.411615506.$$

Comment: I don't get how you relate $Q(s)$ and $L(s)$ (except if $q = 1$)

Comment: If you multiply a number $m$ that is not divisible by a prime $p$ by $p^{q+k}$ then $\tau$ goes up by a factor of $q+k+1.$

Comment: @Marko Riedel - Your solution answers my immediate needs. I would like to share the most general result with you. It is NOT my work. It comes from another site I frequent - and the author is Mark Hennings from the United Kingdom. Since I am just learning to use MathJax, it is beyond my abilities to present the whole proof here. But I'll give the final General Expression result:  If you prime factorize $k=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2} \cdots p_m^{a_m}$ the general form becomes $\tfrac{1}{36}\pi^4\prod_{j=1}^m\big(a_j+1-a_jp_j^{-2}\big)$ This agrees with your two results that you provided for my examples.